# -Dpig.additional.jars with files on both HDFS and the local filesystem

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

How do I pass jars from both my local filesystem and the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) to `-Dpig.additional.jars`?

Let's say I have two jars:

1. /home/local/myjar1.jar
2. hdfs:///user/notlocal/myjar2.jar

The first jar is in my local directory. The second jar is in HDFS.

I want to run `test_script.pig1` on the Hadoop cluster and include the above two jars in `-Dpig.additional.jars`.

`pig -x mapreduce -f test_script.pig1 -Dpig.additional.jars=/home/local/myjar1.jar:hdfs:///user/notlocal/myjar2.jar` does not work because `hdfs` is treated as a file (since a colon follows it).

How do I make this work?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to pass jars on the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) to my local filesystem.

I came up with a workaround: Move the HDFS jars to the local filesystem.

Let's say I have two jars:

1. /home/local/myjar1.jar
2. hdfs:///user/notlocal/myjar2.jar

The first jar is in my local directory. The second jar is in HDFS.

I copied `myjar2.jar` on HDFS to my local filesystem:

`hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/notlocal/myjar2.jar /home/local/`

I then did:

`pig -x mapreduce -f test_script.pig1 -Dpig.additional.jars=/home/local/myjar1.jar:/home/local/myjar2.jar`